# UK visa expiry date and the date of leaving the UK

Tags: visas, uk, tourist-visas, standard-visitor-visas

I have a UK tourist visa which expires on July 23rd. Can I leave the UK on July 23rd or should it be before this date? Also, I will be traveling by July 18th. Would it be a problem to travel at the last week of my visa?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no problem entering Britain within the period of validity of your visa, even if you enter in the last week.

Your visa entitles you to stay until midnight on 23rd July, so flying 
out that day will be fine.

However, you should consider the possibility that your flight might be delayed or cancelled. If you're flying a route that's served, say, only once per week, and your flight is cancelled, you could find yourself overstaying up to a week.

Better to go a day or two early and avoid any trouble should you wish to apply for another visa in the future.

Comment: Please clarify "midnight on 23rd July" :-) It is 07-23 24:00, isn't it?

Comment: @bipll It is the _end_ of the day, yes.